# Managing Complex Repository Changes Between Branches

Tags: git

I'm working on a project for a client who has a large Angular app. They work off the `develop` branch, and have a couple feature branches that have been around for a while and are not currently ready to merge into `develop`. Recently, they implemented eslint, and have an `eslint-upgrade` branch which should be merged into a feature branch before submitting a pull request into `develop`.

What I'm working on is restructuring the app to use [Nx](https://nx.dev). I've got a branch of my own, `nx-conversion`, where I've already converted the app and got it building and working with Nx. I worked on that branch before the `eslint-upgrade` branch was created and finished.

What I'm looking for is some guidance on best ways to move forward so that the app restructure goes smoothly when we need to merge the other feature branches. I don't want it to be a nightmare for the next several months while we wait for those features to be merged.

I am also not sure the best way to get the changes from `eslint-upgrade` into `nx-conversion`. I tried

```
git rebase eslint-upgrade
```

from the `nx-conversion` branch, because I thought it would essentially remove my commits, apply the changes from `eslint-upgrade`, then replay my commits back on top and all the changes I made would still work, but that is not what happened.

If there's a way to do this, I'm definitely open to trying it. If the answer is "wait until the feature branches are merged, then restructure the app, I'm fine with that too. Although I don't know how long that will be so I'd definitely prefer not to wait for too long.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "but that is not what happened". Well, what happened? I assume lots of conflicting changes. And if there are conflicting changes there's no easy way around it.

Comment: Yes, there were many conflicts, and the files that I'd moved were not moved to the same location. Stuff like that. I was hoping maybe I'd missed a step and there was a way to get it to work. 

Answer (score 0):

> best way to get the changes from eslint-upgrade into nx-conversion. I tried `git rebase eslint-upgrade` from the `nx-conversion` branch

Good idea, wrong order.

To to get the changes from `eslint-upgrade` into `nx-conversion`, you would first:

- rebase `eslint-upgrade` on top of `nx-conversion`,
- the switch to `nx-conversion` and (trivial) merge  `eslint-upgrade`

That is:

```sh
git switch eslint-upgrade
git rebase nx-conversion
# resolve any conflict there

git switch nx-conversion
git merge eslint-upgrade
```